# BibLaTeX cite year and letter

Tags: biblatex

I'm using the BibLaTeX package with these options: `backend=biber, citestyle=authoryear, maxcitenames=2, mincitenames=1, maxbibnames=99, language=italian`.

If I have two documents from the same author and the same year, the command `\cite{work1}` and `\cite{work2}` will output `Author A and Author B, XXXXa` and `Author A and Author B, XXXXb`. I'd like to redefine the command `\cite{}` in order to output `Author A and Author B (XXXXa)` and `Author A and Author B (XXXXb)`. I tried using the `citeauthor` and `citeyear` commands, but the `citeyear` does not take the letter into account (it just prints `Author A and Author B (XXXX)` if I do `\renewcommand{cite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}`)

I know there is a way to do it, but I don't know how. Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `\textcite`. In an `authoryear`-like style it will produce citations of the form 'Author (Year)'.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

ipsum \textcite{knuth:ct:b}

dolor \textcite{knuth:ct:c}

Lorem \parencite{worman}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: ipsum Knuth (1986a)//dolor Knuth (1986b)]

---

If you need to separate the author from the year, you could use `\citeauthor` and the starred version of a citation command, like `\parencite*`. But in any case it is not recommended to put two `\...cite` commands into the same `\newcommand` as that can mess with pre- and postnotes as well as citation tracking. Usually it is possible to achieve the same by creating a single citation command directly with `\DeclareCiteCommand` (and in that case the command exists already, so you don't need to do anything).